# how to join Hibernate Hierarchy classes using Spring Data JPA CriteriaQuery?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to use spring data criteria query join for hibernate hierarchical classes. can someone help to solve the join queries 
  **I want to create join between these tables to get all persons which has phone number=? or zipCode=?**

```
   Ex. 

`@Entity
class Person {
  @ManyToOne(optional=false, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name="address_id", nullable=false, updatable=false)
   Address address;
   //setter/getter
}

@Entity
@Table(name="address")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="address_type", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("address")
abstract class Address {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name="address_id", unique=true)
  private Long addressId;

  @Column(name="address_type", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
  private String addressType;

}


@Entity
@Table(name="personal_address")
@DiscriminatorValue("personal")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="address_id")
public class PersonalAddress extends Address {

  @OneToOne(optional=false, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="phone_id", nullable=false, updatable=false)
  private Phone phone;

   @Column
   private String zipCode;

 }





 public Specification<Person> build(String zipCode) {
        return new Specification<Person>() {

            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Person> root,                                 
                                CriteriaQuery<?> query, 
                                CriteriaBuilder builder) {

              Join<Person, Address> joinref = root.join("address");

              ??? How to add further join here to get the data from PersonalAddress class?????

     }                  
`
```